# How to place text Over Image in SAPUI5?

Tags: sapui5

How to place centred **Text** over image in SAPUI5? Something like this example in html: 
https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_transparency

Answer (score 0):

```
<html:div class="background">
   <html:div class="transbox">
        <html:p>
             This is some text that is placed in the transparent box.
        </html:p>
  </html:div>
```

> xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" add this name space to your view.

- Use the same CSS given in w3school example you have used
- This example is for XML view only 
  [image: Screen shot of my SAPUI5 app below]

Comment: Hi Santosh, Thank you. But, my question is how we can achieve this in SAPUI5. Through HTML am able to do through w3schools code.

Comment: The above code works in SAPUI5 XML view. Which view are you using in your application?. Screen shot has been added to the answer done in SAPUI5 XML view